# How important an ADSL/VDSL microfilter is?

Tags: networking, router, modem, adsl, vdsl

I bought the netgear dm200 ADSL/VDSL modem to change the existing modem/router in my home. I first switched the microfilter, and connected the old hardware (Not the dm200) to the new microfilter. I have noticed that my old hardware (telephone and internet modem/router), stops working even if the only thing I have changed is the microfilter. If I put back my old microfilter everything works fine. How come? I thought that these filters are only Low Pass filters which have no reall importance what hardware you plug into them. The only difference I could notice on the microfilters without opening them is that on my new filter it says VDSL filter, and the other ADSL.

Thank for anyone who reads this message.

Comment: Aside from the differences, don't most modems already have an internal filter?

Comment: @grawity - not in my experience. You need low pass filters covering all devices other then the VDSL, otherwise phone calls can kill the Internet.

Comment: @mashtock is it possible you have the filter the wrong way round or its a faulty one?

Comment: I really hope that the filter is not a faulty one, because it is new from the box.. Also even if I wanted to plug in the filter the wrong way, I don't think it's physically possible. The filter looks like the one in the image in this wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DSL_filter

Comment: You use the filter only on phone handsets, old-style acoustic modems, and fax machines.  IOW devices that use the low-frequency voice band of the phone line need a filter.  Do not put a filter on the line to the ADSL/VDSL modem!  The xDSL modem requires the full spectrum of the phone line.